# Compare audio spectra to find differences

Tags: signal-processing, audio-processing

I have some audio recordings of a rotating machine, one when the machine is working fine, and the other one when there is a problem. By ear, we can ear a difference, but when I compute the FFT spectra of the two recordings, the spectra look pretty much the same (even with the smallest bins). So I wonder if there is alternatives to FFT or if I'm not doing it right. My goal is to spot the difference that we ear, automatically so that I can be notified every time a machine is not working as it should be.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to upload a short example of working versus not-working machine? Can be as little as 5 seconds for each?

Comment: I did two videos to have good audio : 

https://youtu.be/XWMcnIFg218
https://youtu.be/0iWvlH5bZmg

When I processed them I reduced the frequency window (from 100 Hz to 1 or 2 kHz) so that I got rid of the noises that weren't useful.

Comment: Get error, "video is private". Has to be set to Unlisted for others with the link to access

Comment: Sorry, might be good now, by the way thanks for your answer

Comment: Those clips are great. Added an answer below now with a superquick analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one looks at this data in the Time-Frequency domain, a spectrogram, the differences are clearly visible. In this image I have opened the audio clips in Audacity, and switched to spectrogram view (using menu dropdown by the name on the track).

[image]
In normal operation (top row), one see a pretty clear tonal content at <400 Hz, and with a very clear component around 2000kHz.
In the anomalous condition (bottom row), one sees periodic bursts of energy covering the entire frequency range.

These two patterns should be easily distinguishable using a Machine Learning model (given enough data). For example a small Convolutional Neural Network, or a Recurrent Neural Network on the spectrograms. This kind of usecase is usually approached with an Anomaly Detection setup, where one trains the model only on normal data. Labeled anomalous data is however extremely useful for validation.

For reference, the settings I used in Audacity were as follows:

[image]

Regards, Jon Nordby, CTO @ Soundsensing AS, experts in machine hearing

Comment: I think the Machine Learning thing it's too heavy for this task. I went deeper into the spectrum analysis because I was only focused on the frequencies under 500 Hz and your right there's a big difference around 2 kHz. Thank you !

Comment: Why would Machine Learning be too heavy for this task? The ML for this should be able to run on a simple microcontroller.

Comment: It's more about the battery, I need to save as much battery as I could. I'm far from being a specialist, but I suppose that ML does burn quite a lot of battery, or at least more than a simple algorithm right ?

Comment: I would estimate it at under 100 milliwatt using a Cortex M4F type device

Comment: Oh Okay I thought it was bigger. 
I watched your conference on audio classification and it was pretty interesting. I'm new to this field.
So for the moment I'm trying to create an audio dataset, how much data do you think I need to use an ML algorithm ? 
And do you know a library that will work well with this application ? thx :)

Comment: The most important is that your dataset covers all the variation that can be expected, especially the range of "normal" states of the machine(s) of interest. For example: different models of the machine, different settings on the machinery, different operator styles, different operating conditions etc.
Assuming that you apply anomaly detection, then an absolute minimum of 100 labeled instances for validation and testing. And at least 10-100x that in unlabeled data for training. If a couple of seconds is enough per instance that is not so many minutes though.

Comment: I talk a bit about data collection in this presentation, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1H63PewtDbo

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest examining the difference of the signals in time rather than in frequency. Normalize the energy of the two signals, find the optimal shift that maximizes the correlation between them, and then look at the arithmetic-difference between the signals to see if that accounts for what your ears are hearing.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try that this week